# Set height of Windows Vista taskbar buttons

Tags: windows, windows-vista, taskbar

I have the taskbar on the left side of the screen because my monitor is so wide, and the buttons are a bit too flat for my liking. How can I increase their height, so that they look more like Windows 7 buttons? Or, even better, display large symbols (32x32 px) in them instead of the usual small ones?

Answer (score 1):

My first though was changing the registry but I doubt there's anything in there that specifies icons size. My second guess would then be a theme-ing software to completely change the view. You could make everything look like Vista, then get some kind of Win7 taskbar clone.

See if you can find something on http://www.wincustomize.com/

EDIT:
I also found this: http://www.vista4beginners.com/Larger-Quick-Launch-icons which allows you to change the size of the quick launch icons (and, might I add, makes them look alot nicer).

For running programs, try this hack:
Follow the instructions here http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/191509-taskbar-icons.html
Instead of putting a value of -255 in the box, put 40 or 42 instead. This will not make the icon itself bigger, but will make the button have a larger height. From here you can remove the text from the running programs icons. This gives a sort of Windows 7 look:

[image]

Note: the screenshot above is also using a skin to get a different taskbar theme I think.

Comment: I found the "caption icon" size in the (old) Windows display settings ... they actually increase the icon size of the taskbar buttons and tray icons, but also that of the "X" (close window) icon. And I found a software to increase the height of the taskbar buttons, but I don't find the page now, and I don't want to install software for that purpose (it's a computer at my employer's office). I still think that the software only changes a registry setting, so it should be there.

Comment: Check my edit and see if there's anything there that helps.

Comment: OK, my quick launch icons are already large, but I will definitely look into this regedit thing tomorrow! To bad that it says "doesn't work if taskbar is left or right" at the top of the page, though.

Comment: I'm also looking at the registry to see if I can find an appropriate key to modify. I'll post an answer if I find anything.